# onclick function is not defined for dynamically generated input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering why the code below is not working for me.

What I want to do is simply to print something on the console whenever an input field is clicked.

I am generating the input fields by clicking the button "Click me". Each input has an `onclick` attribute looking like this: `onclick="popup()"`.

Can somebody explain why what I am trying to do wouldn't work?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        
    function popup(){            
      console.log("clicked");            
    } 
        
    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
        $('body').append('<input type="aText" id="inputField" onclick="popup()">');
    });                
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
<button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>
    
<div id = "range-calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the `popup()`  function in outer from `$(document).ready(function()` .

**why?**

if you call the `popup` function its undefined because its defined only on `$(document).ready(function()` function not with global .so place with outer its call the global `popup()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    $('body').append('<input type="aText" id="inputField" onclick="popup()">')
  })

})
  function popup() {
    console.log("clicked");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>

<div id="range-calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `popup()` function outside of `$(document).ready(function()` function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    $('body').append('<input type="aText" id="inputField" onclick="popup()">')
})      

});

function popup(){
    console.log("clicked");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>

<div id = "range-calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
function popup(){

    console.log("clicked");

}   

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    $('body').append('<input type="aText" id="inputField" onclick="popup()">');
});      
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the following code.

```
$(document).on('click','#inputField',function(e){
 // code goes here.
});
```